# Dimir Doppelganger becoming Lazav, Dimir Mastermind

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a few clarification questions regarding what happens after I use the activated ability of [Dimir Doppelganger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=83850) to target a [Lazav, Dimir Mastermind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366469) that's sitting in a graveyard. For simplicity, I assume that the only card in play before the ability resolves is the Dimir Doppelganger, which has never used it's ability before.

Firstly, am I correct in saying that the card I have on the battlefield after resolution, in effect, has the name `Lazav, Dimir Mastermind`, is of the type `Legendary Creature - Shapeshifter`, and has card text which reads:

> Hexproof
>
> Whenever a creature card is put into an opponent's graveyard from anywhere, you may have Lazav, Dimir Mastermind become a copy of that card except its name is still Lazav, Dimir Mastermind, it's legendary in addition to its other types, and it gains hexproof and this ability.
>
> 1{U}{B}: Exile target creature card from a graveyard. Lazav, Dimir Mastermind becomes a copy of that card and gains this ability.

Assuming this is correct, and I use the activated ability again to target another creature in a graveyard -- let's say [Grizzly Bears](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=155) -- then the card I have in play is now named `Grizzly Bears`, of type `Creature - Bear` and has only the activated ability of the original doppelganger (losing hexproof and the triggered ability of Lazav.)

And finally, if I instead choose to use the triggered ability my doppel-Lazav in response to a creature entering an opponent's graveyard -- we can assume it's [Grizzly Bears](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=155) again -- then my card now named `Lazav, Dimir Mastermind`, of type `Legendary Creature - Bear` and reads:

> Hexproof
>
> Whenever a creature card is put into an opponent's graveyard from anywhere, you may have Lazav, Dimir Mastermind become a copy of that card except its name is still Lazav, Dimir Mastermind, it's legendary in addition to its other types, and it gains hexproof and this ability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your grizzly bear scenarios are either/or (and you're not doing one after another)...

You are correct. The card will come back as either a Lazav copy or a Doppleganger copy and it depends entirely on which card's copy ability you use.

It's the ability itself (of either lazav or the doppleganger) that causes the copy to retain the previous abilities, because it uses the wording: `"gains this ability."`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on 2: response was probably the wrong word in that last paragraph. I simply meant that that if I chose to use the triggered ability on the stack and let Lazav become a copy of Grizzly Bears after the bears die.

Comment: @cljacobs I've been editing my answer because I believe I misred the question the first time.  The answer I had before assumed that the first scenario was using the Lazahv ability and the last one was using the doppleganger ability